# Java text to applet converter ... is there such a thing?

Tags: java

Let's say you have this program:

```
public class sample

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
           System.out.println("Hello world!");
        }
}
```

... is there a converter that will turn it into this:

import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.*;

```
public class sample extends JApplet
{

    public static JTextArea area;

    public void init()
    {

        area = new JTextArea();
        add(area);
        area.append("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

I mean, I can do it by hand... but it would take some time.

Comment: Start typing, there is no converter.

Comment: If there is such converter, it would wipe out a whole clan of front-end developers! ;)

Comment: *"I mean, I can do it by hand... but it would take some time."* Would it? I guess like anything else, the last 10% might drag. The 90% -- creating a `PrintStream` implementation that writes to the `JTextArea` and calling `System.setOut` with it, that would be fairly quick. And if you had another area from which you drew input for an `InputStream` then use `System.setIn`. Probably another `PrintStream` for `System.setErr` as well. In all, that sounds like an hour or so of work, and has to be at least 90%, probably 95%, of the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

Various IDEs that have RAD (rapid application development) features will autogenerate code behind your back in some circumstances, but that code is usually ugly and non maintainable.

So, for best results, continue typing...